# Which LINQ expression do I need for this, without looping?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have an MSSQL database with `LINQ to SQL`.
I have three tables.
`Requests -> id, string name`
`Results -> id, requestID, int jumps`
`Places -> id, resultID, int location`
Then, using an input `string`, I need to get an *ICollectable* or *array* or something of `Place` which meets the following:
Each `Request` that has `name`=`input`, take its ID.[you can assume only one has]
Each `Result` that has `requestID`=`ID[from above]` - take its `id`.
Each `Place` that has `resultID=`'id[from above]' - append to array for further processing.

I made it by looping on all `Results` and then executing another `LINQ` statement, but its extremely slow [about 500ms for a single request!]. **Can I make it any faster?**

Thank you!

Edit: Whoops, I also need it grouped by result. aka a List of List of Places, while each inner list contains one column from `Result`.

Comment: How would you write this query in SQL? (Hint: it involves Joins). For better or worse, LINQ maps fairly closely to SQL DQL, so looking at it from that approach may be enlightening.

Comment: [Basic LINQ Query Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform table joins in Linq2Sql using the join keyword:

```
var places = from request in Requests 
             join result in Results on request.Id equals result.requestID
             join place in Places on result.Id equals place.ResultId
             where request.name = input
             select place;
```

Comment: OP would like the `name` to match the `input`, not the `id`

Comment: I also need it grouped by `Results`.

Answer (score 2):

Somthing like

```
Requests.Where(r => r.name == input).Results.Places.Select();
```

If this is too slow then I expect you need some indexes on your database.

If you don't have the relationships in your model then you need to establish some foreign key constraints on your tables an rebuild your model.